# Use dynamic named range for pivot table data source

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table, named-ranges

I have a table with increasing data for pivot table charts.
And I'd like to have a function to check and remove duplicates in the table if any.

This is what I have done, say my table is called Table, then in the name manager:

1. create range called Header, Header=Table[#Headers]
2. create range called Body, Body=unique(Table)
3. create range called Data, Data=vstack(Header,Body)

But when I use Data as data source for the pivot table, it gives me alter message "Reference is invalid"

Is it possible to use dynamic named range for pivot table data source? Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you will need to actually put that data into a range, then you can refer to that range.  For example in a hidden sheet in A1 put `=Data`  then in the data source refere to it as `Sheet3!A1#`

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your reply. I actually tried to use A1# as pivot table data source first. But once I apply it, the data range change into fixed range, not dynamic. I only notice that after adding more data to the Table, but no update after refresh data.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table "tblData" that I want to extract a subset and pass on to a pivot table. On a new sheet "SubTable", I put these formulas in cell A1 & A2:

`=tblData[#Headers]`

`=FILTER(tblData,tblData[VALID]="Y")`

This gives me the headers from the original table, plus the data from the table matching the filter, and it looks like a table - but it isn't one, and can't be used dynamically in a pivot. So I created a named range, "subtData":

`=OFFSET(SubTable!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(SubTable!$A:$A),COUNTA(tblData[#Headers]))`

This name can then be used in a pivot table. If the filter returns no data, the headers and 1 row of "#CALC!" are returned to the pivot table so it isn't invalidated.